# C++ (int) static cast weird error

Tags: c++

I have a very weird error with c++.
I have two values, max and singleStep. The number of steps is stepsInt and/or stepsDbl:

```
max = 100;
singleStep = 0.1;
// This means that I have 100/0.1 = 1000 numbers betwwen 0 and 100
double stepsDbl = max/singleStep;
int stepsInt = (int)(stepsDbl);
cout << stepsDbl << stepsInt;
```

You can expect an output like this:

```
1000 1000
```

However I'm getting this output:

```
1000 999
```

What is more, if I try a different value for singleStep, for instance 0.2, I get again wrong values

```
500 499
```

I don't know what is happening but is pretty weird... If anyone has a solution for this problem I would appreciate that solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
int stepsInt = (int)floor(stepsDbl+.5);
```

The "problem" you're seeing is because of the way floating point numbers are stored internally.

Answer (score 1):

`(int)` casts round toward zero, and `(double)` arithmetic is inherently unreliable (look up floating point math).  `operator<<(double)` rounds to nearest, so a value like `999.999999999999` resulting from accumulated FP inaccuracy will print as `1000` directly and `999` when naïvely cast to `(int)`.

Comment: It's actually perfectly reliable.

Comment: @Blindy: in Captain Pedantic mode, it's perfectly reliable for what it does but it's presented as something for which it is distinctly *un*reliable. That kind of hair-splitting just confuses the issue and is unhelpful.

Comment: Some more careful wording will help un-confuse the issue :)

Comment: @Blindy: You're failing at it. I answered the user's problem, and in context what I said is correct (it is unreliable *for the intended use*; if the OP cared about your preferred context, they would not have needed to ask the question to start with). Pointlessly confusing pedanticism is *still* unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers on your platform cannot exactly represent numbers which do not have a finite binary expansion, so you will naturally have uncertainty when using those numbers. Use rationals instead and keep "0.1" as "1/10" when possible.

("Finite binary expansion" means "finite sum of powers of two". 1/5 is not a finite sum of powers of 2, and neither is 1/3 nor 1/10.)